# BigQuery - not caching identical queries on unchanged data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery API to run a query with the following code:

```
request = service.jobs().query(projectId="myProject", body={
    "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest",
    "query": "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM widgets",
    "maxResults": 5000,
    "timeoutMs": 10000,
    "useQueryCache": True,
    "useLegacySql": True
})
response = request.execute()
```

The underlying data is unchanging, and the query is unchanging. I'd expect a cache hit - but the response is returning `cacheHit` as `False`.  Mysteriously, however, `totalBytesProcessed` equals zero even though row data is being returned.

Is this a bug with BigQuery? Am I being charged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery is "smart" enough to realize that you are just "asking" for count of the rows in table.  For this to happen it uses [meta-tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#using_meta-tables)
Use of meta-tables does not incur any co$t
So, no - you are not being charged for this specific query

Comment: thank you!  is it safe to say that if `totalBytesProcessed` is zero, the charge is always zero?

Comment: Formally, you should rather look for `totalBytesBilled`. But in case of zero bytes - they are the same and charge is zero. Yes

Comment: that is hugely helpful - i really appreciate it